# Unable to connect mysql from docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, database-connection

I have created a docker-compose file it has two services with `Go` and `Mysql`. It creates container for go and mysql. Now i am running code which try to connect to mysql database which is running as a docker container. but i get error.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: golang
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "49160:8800"
    links:
      - "mysql"
    depends_on:
      - "mysql" 

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testDB
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**Error while connecting to mysql database**

```
golang   | 2019/02/28 11:33:05 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
golang   | 2019/02/28 11:33:05 http: panic serving 172.24.0.1:49066: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
golang   | goroutine 19 [running]:
```

**Connection with MySql Database**

```
func DB() *gorm.DB {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(mysql:3306)/testDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connection Established")
    return db
}
```

**EDIT:Updated docker file**

```
FROM golang:latest 
RUN go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm
RUN go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh .
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
WORKDIR /go/src/app
ADD . src
EXPOSE 8800
CMD ["go", "run", "src/main.go"]
```

I am using gorm package which lets me connet to the database

Answer (score 10):

`depends_on` is not a verification that MySQL is actually ready to receive connections. It will start the second container once the database container is running regardless it was ready for connections or not which could lead to such an issue with your application as it expects the database to be ready which might not be true.

Quoted from [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started.

There are many tools/scripts that can be used to solve this issue like [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) which `sh` compatible in case your image based on `Alpine` for example (You can use [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) if you have bash in your image)

All you have to do is to add the script to your image through `Dockerfile` then use this command in `docker-compose.yml` for the service that you want to make it wait for the database.

**What comes after `--` is the command that you would normally use to start your application**

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: golang
    ...
        command: ["./wait-for", "mysql:3306", "--", "go", "run", "myapplication"]
    links:
      - "mysql"
    depends_on:
      - "mysql" 

  mysql:
    image: mysql
  ...
```

> I have removed some parts from the docker-compose for easier readability.
>
> Modify this part `go run myapplication` with the `CMD` of your golang image.

See [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

---

Another issue that will rise after you solve the connection issue will be as the following:

Setting `MYSQL_USER` with `root` value will cause a failure in MySQL with this error message:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

This is because this user already exist in the database and it tries to create another. if you need to use the root user itself you can use only this variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` or change the value of `MYSQL_USER` so you can securely use it in your application instead of the root user.

**Update**: In case you are getting not found and the path was correct, you might need to write the command as below:

```
command: sh -c "./wait-for mysql:3306 -- go run myapplication"
```

Comment: can you tell me what exact code i should write to get rid of this.

Comment: have you added it to the image and made it executable ?

Comment: No i have not added it to the image. Please tell me how do i add it to the image? Though i have written it as  COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh in DOCKER File

Comment: Please post your updated Dockerfile to the question so i can check it, if you already used `COPY` then it means you have it in the image and make it executable

Comment: KIndly check my updated question. I have added the docker file

Comment: Actually the mysql container wont work correctly regardless of the wrong ip that appears in the log, so please read the second part of my question carefully which is related to the usage of `MYSQL_USER` variable

Comment: let me know how it will work because wait_for_it is not found

Comment: you need to enter inside the container by a starting a new container then try to execute the script manually to check if it actually there or not or you need to fix permissions and so on as you expected to find the script

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using latest version of docker compose you don't need the link argument in you app service. I quote the docker compose documentation `Warning: The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it,` https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

I think the solution is to use the `networks` argument. This create a docker network and add each service to it.

Try this

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: golang
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "49160:8800"
    networks:
     - my_network
    depends_on:
      - "mysql" 

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
     - my_network
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testDB
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
volumes:
  dbdata:
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

By the way, if you only connect to Mysql from your app service you don't need to expose the mysql port. If the containers runs in the same network they can reach all ports inside this network.

If my example doesn't works try this
run the docker compose and next go into the app container using 
`docker container exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash`
Install `ping` in order to test connection and then run ping mysql.

Comment: I tried the compose file in the question and just ping-ed mysql, it seemed to work fine and displayed the correct IP. 
In the question it tries to connect to ` 127.0.0.1:3306` localhost, I wonder why.

Comment: I am not able to connect to mysql server. Tell me what i suppose to enter here root:root@tcp(mysql:3306)/testDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local

Comment: I have done some r&d and got to know that this issue is due to docker startup ordrer

Comment: Kindly suggest solution for the above issue.