# How to call the entry-point of redmine docker image?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get redmine running in docker. I'm new to both.

I'm using the "default" redmine image (version 3.3, because version 4.X is not yet supported by redmine mobile apps).

I have the issue that the redmine container starts before the db is ready, and fails. So I just want to try and build a "sleep" in the container using "command", but I need to work out how to start redmine using "command". From what I found, I need to call "/docker-entrypoint.sh", but this doesn't work:

```
command: >
/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I think this is the actual start script (from the current version:)
[docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/redmine/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Comment: you can use `entrypoint` keyword in docker-compose.yml but i think you don't need to call the entrypoint itself. you might need to try this in case of mysql with port 3306 or postgres with port 5432 `command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]` assuming that you have added wait-for-it script to redmine image https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: You can find a full details about the database issue in my answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033751/2336650

Comment: @MostafaHussein Hi. The `"./wait-for", "mysql:3306", "--"` part I found already, what I'm looking for is the `"go", "run", "myapplication"` part, for redmine specifically. Is that what `"rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"` does? In that case, this would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `entrypoint` keyword instead of `command` in your docker-compose.yml however for the issue you have with the database you don't actually need to call the `entrypoint` itself. You can add [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) or [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) to redmine image by extending it through using Dockerfile then in your docker-compose.yml you can use this as a command:

In case of MySQL use port 3306 or use port 5432 in case of PostgreSQL and change `db` word according to the database service name inside your docker-compose.yml

The rest of the command which comes after `--` is based on the `CMD` line in redmine's Dockerfile as shown in [here](https://github.com/docker-library/redmine/blob/master/Dockerfile.template#L161)

```
command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

More explanation can be found in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033751/2336650)

Comment: My redmine still fails, but at least it starts, and fails with another message, so this seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The current issue related to redmine itself ? I mean if you need more assist let me know about the current error

Comment: If I can't debug it myself, I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: OK. This didn't quite work `/bin/bash -c "sleep 25 && rails server -b 0.0.0.0"`, but this did: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 25 && /docker-entrypoint.sh rails server -b 0.0.0.0"`. Problem solved. :)

Comment: May I now what was the issue with the first solution? Have you tried with wait-for-it?  Or you didn't want to build your own image?

Comment: I just didn't want to build my own image (for now).