# best practice for flask migrations in kubernetes

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, database-migration

Working on a project which is a k8s service which is implemented using flask.

As part of the deployment, I'd like to run db migrations before the app starts execution.

I was wondering what is considered "best practice", and why.

Just mentioning here some of the ideas I had in mind:

- An [entrypoint.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223961) script
- An [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)
- A [job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)
- A [configmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506354)

if you had other approach/technique, be my guest :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of your list, only "job" will run a single time. The rest will run as times as your have replicas and it will happen on every pod restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice would be to wrap all your app-related Kubernetes files in a helm chart, add the migration in a post-upgrade-hook which will ensure that is only run one time.

The problem with `entrypoint.sh` is that if you have more than 1 pod in your deployment, the migration will be run more than once...

More info on helm chart hooks:

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/