# run script on docker file to wait postgress

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hello i'm new to docker and linux and i don't know how to run a script for my docker to run after my postgress

this is my script:

```
until psql -c '\l'; do
  echo >&2 "$(date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S) Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
echo >&2 "$(date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S) Postgres is up - executing command"

exec ${@}
```

my docker file :

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY wait-pg.sh ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

RUN chmod +x /wait-pg.sh

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

my docker compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db-pg:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db-pg
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ci-postgres-data:/data

  ci-api:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-api
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - /home/node/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
    depends_on:
      - db-pg
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10m'
        max-file: '5'

volumes:
  ci-postgres-data:
```

If someone can help me like I would in my docker compose and in my dockerfile.
I would like to know how I can add my script to my docker file and docker compose

Comment: Please consider using `healthchecks`, if you want to just check whether postgres is up or not

Comment: I tried with healthchecks, but I was not successful, I saw that in version 3 condition in dependcy was discontinued

Comment: can u helpme with script and healthchecks ?

Comment: The answer in the following question can help you [Unable to connect mysql from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925218/unable-to-connect-mysql-from-docker-container)

Comment: @MostafaHussein i try with this but I'm not just using the docker-compose so I'm in doubt

Comment: what do you mean by not just docker-compose? the idea of the answer above is to add `wait-for` script inside your image and use it in addition to the original cmd which will make the application wait for the database before going further

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein can u give me one example with this code please?

Comment: This is an example you can use https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/, Just copy the script inside your docker image

Comment: i need to put my sh in my project folder?

Comment: It looks like you copy the `wait-pg.sh` script into your image, but you don't actually run it; it should be part of your `CMD` (or the `ENTRYPOINT`).

Comment: @David Maze can u reply with this? i try and not sucess.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

WORKDIR /home/node/api

COPY wait-pg.sh ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

USER node

RUN yarn

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

Please try the below `docker-compose.yml` in which `depends_on`, `healthcheck` and `links` are added as `web` service depends on `db` service.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  ci-api:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-api
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - /home/node/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
    links:
      - db-pg
    depends_on:
      - db-pg
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10m'
        max-file: '5'

  db-pg:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db-pg
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ci-postgres-data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  ci-postgres-data:
```

Comment: i got this error: db-pg     | 2020-06-01 00:15:48.696 UTC [67] FATAL:  database "postgress" does not exist

Comment: which values are you passing where `variables` are mentioned

Comment: SERVER_PORT=4000
DB_HOST=db-pg
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=spirit
DB_PASS=api
DB_NAME=emasa_ci

Comment: Can you try with `'2.1'` version?

Comment: get FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Comment: Can you post output of `lsof -n -i:5432 | grep LISTEN`

Comment: And apart from that, have done a small tweak as will in docker-compose, can you try again?

Comment: i try with this and got same errror :  2020-06-01 00:27:57.872 UTC [109] FATAL:  database "spirit" does not exist